# INSERT statement in joined table

Tags: php, html, insert, phpmyadmin

I have 3 table:

`tblNames`:

```
|  id  |   firstname   |   lastname   |
+------+---------------+--------------+
|  1   |   John        |   Smith      |
```

`tblJosbs` (this table accepts multiple checkbox value at the same time):

```
|  id  |   jobs                |
+------+-----------------------+
|  1   |   Nurse               |
+------+-----------------------+
|  2   |   Call Center Agent   |
+------+-----------------------+
|  3   |   Police              |
```

`tblNamesJobs` (this table is used to `JOIN` the other 2 tables):

```
|  id  |   name_id   |   jobs_id   |
+------+-------------+-------------+
|  1   |   1         |   1         |
+------+-------------+-------------+
|  2   |   1         |   2         |
+------+-------------+-------------+
|  3   |   1         |   3         |
```

All is fine but can someone show me the `INSERT` statement for the 3rd table I should use to when I will add new information?

Comment: What you mean. For insert data you can use just simple INSERT

Answer (score 2):

For example add record that **John Smith** is a **Call Center Agent**

```
insert into tblNamesJobs (name_id,jobs_id )
values (
         select id from tblNames where 
                firstname='John' 
                and lastname='Smith' limit 1
         ,
         select id from tblJosbs where jobs='Call Center Agent' limit 1
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO tblNamesJobs (name_id, jobs_id) VALUES (XXXX,YYYY)
```

That is assuming the table's id is auto-incrementing.

It should be noted that both the name_id and jobs_id columns in the "joiner" table should be foreign keys to the respective columns in the other table.

Edit - Valex's answer goes into more detail about what to do if you don't already have the id values.

If possible, I would recommend using some sort of framework that would handle the "joiner" table for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already depending on tauto increment..you can get the lastinserid, depending on your adapter.
eg. **mysql_insert_id**

for PDO we can use --**PDO::lastInsertId.**

so you will have id's of earlier inserted tables, that you can save in the new one.